# How to get only one column as the result of a query with ActiveAndroid?

Tags: android, activeandroid

How can I get an array with only the column "Name" of my `Category` model?

I can get all my categories using

```
List<Category> categoryList = new Select()
    .from(Category.class)
    .execute();
```

and then create another array with the name of the `Category`, but I guess there is a way to get it directly and I cannot find how.

Comment: I've wondered the same thing for several months. I first thought `new Select("your_column")...execute();` would retrieve columns only but it doesn't.

Comment: No. I created the array myself from the list of Category.

Answer (score 12):

A little late in answering this, but the issue is because SQLiteUtils.rawQuery() makes the assumption that the Id column is always going to be in the cursor result.   Set your columns String[] to {Id, your_column} and you'll be fine.

```
List<Category> categoryList = new Select(new String[]{"Id,your_column"}).from(Category.class).execute();
```

Comment: Note, your id column isn't necessarily `Id`. On Android, mine was `_id`, which is what the typical `ListView` expects.

Comment: Also, if your query has any joins you'll need to specify the table names, otherwise you'll get an ambiguous column error. E.g. `new String[]{"categories.Id,categories.name"}`